# connect points in ggplot based on specific column values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data set called `t`:

```
n <- 12
t <- data.frame(
  V1    = runif(n, 0.12, 0.35),
  V2    = runif(n, 0.25, 0.39),
  group = gl(3, 4, labels = c("a1", "a2", "a3")),
  x     = seq_len(n),
  color = rep(rep.int(c("R", "G"), 2), c(3, 4, 3, 2))
)
```

I created the following plot from this data.

```
p <- ggplot(t, aes(x, colour = color)) +  
  geom_point(aes(y = V1, size = 10)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = V2, size = 10))
```

What I want to do now is to connect the points depending on the group column (e.g, points of group `a1` will be connected with a blue line, points of group `a2` will be connected in a yellow line, ...) and i want the line to be different depending on `V1` and `V2` (dashed line for `V1` and normal line for `V2`).

How this can be done?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I've fixed your dataset to make it easier for others to reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: naming a dataset "t" is not a good idea because it is confusing since there is a function t() as well.

The easiest way is to melt() your dataset first

```
Molten <- melt(t, id.vars = c("group", "x", "color"))
ggplot(Molten, aes(x = x, y = value, colour = group, linetype = variable)) + geom_line()
```

Have a look at the ggplot2 website on how to customise the colours.

Comment: :thank you, but what you wrote will give in total 4 lines, but i have 3 groups and 2 colors. so there should be 6 lines. because each group will get 2 lines(for V1 and for V2)

Comment: I've updated the code. Please use less confusing names in the future. You have a variable named 'color' but you want the colours by the variable 'group'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot your graph without using `melt()`:

```
p <-ggplot(t) + geom_line(aes(x,V2,color=group)) + geom_line(aes(x,V1,color=group), linetype = "dashed")
```